# IPtables used for load balancing but some packets getting dropped

Tags: iptables

I am trying to use `iptables` for load balancing. The rule I have set is as follows wherein I want to route requests coming to my server with IP address `10.x.x.4` to internal IPs of the server `10.x.x.1:1010`, `10.x.x.2:1010` and `10.x.x.3:1010`

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.1:1010
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.2:1010
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.3:1010
```

When I execute it, the first 4 packets gets routed to each IP address correctly. The 5th packet doesn't get routed and is getting dropped.

How do I debug this issue? Should I increment the value passed to `--packet`? What should be the correct rule?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it but from documentation I'm sure that you should increment the `--packet`.

Comment: thank you it worked. I changed the rule to                                                                   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.1:1010                                                        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.2:1010